# Filter data from multiple files at once

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have multiple folders each containing several thousand files. I need to filter each file in each folder based on date & once all the files in a folder are filtered, I need to create a zip file of each folder containing all the filtered data CSVs.

The below function creates a zip file of the individual files which is not really what I want.

One solution that works is creating a new file for every file in a new folder with the filtered data & then creating a zip of the new folder. I don't want to do this as the data files will be repeated across multiple folders & I'll run out of disk space & additionally it's massively time consuming given I am dealing with several terabytes of data

Is there a way I can filter out data from all files at ones into it's own CSV in memory & zip it all up?

```
def filter_data(data, file_name):
     data[pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], format='%Y-%m') >= five_years_ago].to_csv(
            data_store + file_name + '.csv.gz',
            index=False, compression="gzip")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code answers your last question,

> Is there a way I can filter out data from all files at ones into it's own CSV in memory & zip it all up?

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
import shutil

# i refers to the number of the folder
# folderInput_i represent the folder with thousand files
# and the command below imports all files in the folder at onces 

dataPara = dd.read_csv("C:\\______\\______\\Desktop\\folderInput_i\\*.csv")

five_years_ago = "2016-12"
five_years_ago = pd.to_datetime(five_years_ago, format='%Y-%m')

# treatement of all files at once

dataPara = dataPara[dd.to_datetime(dataPara['Date'], format='%Y-%m')  >= five_years_ago]

dataPara.to_csv("C:\\______\\______\\Desktop\\folderOutput_i\\*.csv", index = False)

# to  zip your new folder who contains the filtered data files 

shutil.make_archive('C:\\______\\______\\Desktop\\folderOutput_i.csv.gz','zip',
                    "C:\\______\\______\\Desktop\\folderOutput_i")
```

Comment: This works like a charm. Magnificent. Thank you heaps @Safouane

Comment: the dask dataframe processing is significantly slower compared to pandas dataframe. However, irony is pandas doesn't have the capability read all the csv's at one go as you'd know I'm sure. Your code for archiving is super cool. got through millions of files in about 9 min whereas shell script would take anywhere between 2 to 4 hours depending on what else is running on the box.

Comment: I think that the dask dataframe processing depends on the nature of operations that need to be performed and the size of data, the link below contains some benchmarkings between main data processing packages [Database-like ops benchmark](https://h2oai.github.io/db-benchmark/)

Comment: Thanks for the reference link. It's super informative.

Answer (score 1):

This will find all CSV files inside some start directory (non-recursively), check their creation times (i.e. [`ctime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat_result.st_ctime)) and write them to a zip archive if they're older than the defined cutoff:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile, ZIP_DEFLATED

FIVE_YEARS = 365 * 5 # approximation
cutoff = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=FIVE_YEARS)
start_dir = Path('startdir/')
archive = start_dir / 'archived.zip'

with ZipFile(archive, mode='x', compression=ZIP_DEFLATED) as myzip:
    for csv_file in start_dir.glob('*.csv'):
        ctime = datetime.fromPath(csv_file).stat().st_ctime
        if ctime > cutoff:
            continue # file is newer than the cutoff
        myzip.write(csv_file)
        # csv_file.unlink() # WARNING: destructive, test first!
```

Comment: Thank you Jan. The solution you've supplied is great & I'll refer to it for another use case. What I'm after is to filter out the contents of a file based on the field called 'Date' and create a new file (same operation for all the files in a folder) & once all the files in a folder are processed, create a zip archive from them

Comment: @usert4jju7 I see, that wasn't clear from the question. You could try stringing together several shell tools like `awk`.